# Discrete Math problem with a deck of cards

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

I have a standard deck of 52 cards. How do I find the number of hands of 13 cards that contain 4 cards of the same rank? (A,2-10, J,Q,K)

My initial thought was to choose 10 cards from 49, because 9 are normal cards and the 10th can be any random starting card that will determine what the next 3 cards are. The choose 3 cards from 3 as they must all be the same rank. This must be done for each rank, so it is brought to the 13th power.

$${49 \choose 10}{3 \choose 3}^{13} = {49 \choose 10}^{13}$$

I'm very confused with this question, is this on the right track?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is easier to first count how any ways to get exactly 4 Aces: that is 4 aces, and 1 non-ace.  Then, multiple by the total number of ranks.

Comment: So it would be ((48 choose 9))^13?

Comment: I just realized you want 13-card hands, so strike my comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach fails because you are assuming that the last three cards match the tenth.  There are many more ways for the hand to have four of a kind.

The number of hands that include $4$ aces is ${48 \choose 9}$ because you have that many ways to choose the rest of the cards.  It is tempting to multiply this by $13$ for the number of hands that include four of a kind, but you count hands with two four of a kinds twice, so you need the [inclusion-exclusion principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: In that case, can I do $$({48 \choose 9}^{13}) / 2$$ to eliminate the double?

Comment: No. you need to compute the number of hands that have two four of a kinds.  How many ways to choose the two four of a kinds?  How many ways to choose the rest of the cards?  Then you have the problem of three four of a kinds.  That is a small correction

Comment: Can you please give me more information on how to do what you just suggested? Im really confused on this part

Comment: You would then think the number of ways to get two four of a kinds would be ${13 \choose 2}{44\choose 5}$ because you choose the ranks for the four of a kind and then choose the other cards.  Now you have the problem of the few hands that have three four of a kinds.  If you have understood this you can do that part.

Comment: So it would be $$13 * {48\choose 9} - {13\choose 2}{44\choose 5}$$? Or is it supposed to be to the 13th power?

Comment: @jacob  You still have to add the number of hands with three four of a kinds.  You have counted three times in the $\binom{13}{1}\binom{48}{9}$ term, once for each way of designating one of the three ranks as the rank with four of a kind, and subtracted them three times in the $\binom{13}{2}\binom{44}{5}$ term, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of designating two of the three ranks as the two four of a kinds.  Therefore, you have not counted the hands with three four of a kinds at all, so you must add them to the total.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig could you please elaborate on how I should find the hands with three four of a kinds please?

Comment: @jacob  Choose $3$ ranks from which the four of a kinds are drawn.  That leaves you with $40$ cards from which to draw the remaining card.

Comment: Does the final answer equal $$13 * {48\choose 9} - {13\choose 2}{44\choose 5} + {13\choose 3}{40\choose 1}$$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: @RossMillikan to clarify my understanding, we find ways to choose 1 full rank, 2 full ranks and 3 full ranks. In this case, wouldnt we add them all together? $$13 * {48\choose 9} + {13\choose 2}{44\choose 5} + {13\choose 3}{40\choose 1}$$

Comment: No, your previous one was correct.  When you did $13{48 \choose 9}$ that includes all the cases where there are two four of a kinds twice, so you need to subtract them once.  Look at the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: I see, but how does $${13} * {48\choose 9}$$ include cases with 2 four of a kinds? Doesn't it just mean 13 ways to choose 1 rank, then we are left with 48 cards to choose 9 more, how does include 2 ranks?

Comment: Because four of the other nine cards could be the same rank.  You count $AAAA222234567$ once with the aces the four of a kind and again with the twos.